# fancybox 2.0.3 - autoPlay options

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Is is possible to pause or set autoplay to false when you mouseover fancybox-wrap?

I would like to have autoplay true and change the opacity of a css object to .5 when the mouse is not over the fancybox-wrap.

When I move the mouse over fancybox-wrapI would like autoPlay to be false or paused and change the opacity back to 1.

my current script is:

```
$(".fancyboxItem").fancybox({
    afterLoad : function(){
        var xyz = (this.index);
        var fancyNavString = '<div class="fancyNav">';
        $('a.fancyboxItem').each(function(index){
            if (index==xyz)
            fancyNavString = fancyNavString + '<a class="fancyNavIndex selected" href="javascript:;$.fancybox.jumpto('+(index)+')"></a>';
            else
                fancyNavString = fancyNavString + '<a class="fancyNavIndex" href="javascript:;$.fancybox.jumpto('+(index)+')"></a>';
            });
        var fancyNavString = fancyNavString + '</div><div class="fancyClose"><a href="javascript:;$.fancybox.close()"></a></div>';
        var fancyNavTitle = fancyNavString + '<p>'+(this.index + 1)+' of '+this.group.length+'</p>';
        this.title = fancyNavTitle
        },
    helpers : {
        title : {               
            type : 'inside',
                },              
    },
    'loop'              : true,
    'arrows'            : false,
    'closeBtn'          : false,
    'autoPlay'          : true,
    'playSpeed'         : 4000,
    'margin'            : 50,
    'padding'           : 15,
    'openSpeed'         : 500,
    'closeSpeed'        : 250,
    'nextSpeed'         : 500,
    'prevSpeed'         : 500,
    'openSpeed'         : 500,
    'speedOut'          : 500,
    'openEffect'        : 'fade', 
    'closeEffect'       : 'fade',
    'nextEffect'        : 'fade',
    'prevEffect'        : 'fade',
});
```

});

the test page is:

http://brycedavis.com/html/desertsunflower3.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `afterShow` callback option like:

```
afterShow : function() {
 $(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
  $.fancybox.play();
  $("#targetElement").css({'opacity': 1});
 }, function() {
  $.fancybox.play();
  $("#targetElement").css({'opacity': 0.5});
 });
}
```

The `$.fancybox.play()` API method toggles the slide show on/off